# Luxon: get an array of offsets and untils (like we can in moment-timezone)

Tags: javascript, momentjs, luxon

With the [`moment-timezone`](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone) library I'm currently just retrieving the raw information for a particular timezone and then using that directly in my downstream code.

```
const zone = moment.tz.zone('Europe/London');
```

This is an object containing the following:

```
{
    "name":"Europe/London",
    "abbrs":["GMT","BST","GMT","BST", ...],
    "untils":[-1691964000000,-1680472800000,-1664143200000,-1650146400000, ...],
    "offsets":[0,-60,0,-60,0, ...],
    "population":10000000
}
```

The `offsets` and `untils` arrays are really all I need from `moment`... the rest I handle myself "manually" in the downstream code using the `offsets` and `untils` arrays (or actually just a small subset thereof)... without having to rely on `moment` as a dependency.

Is there an equivalent way to extract `offsets` and `untils` arrays in the [`luxon`](https://github.com/moment/luxon) library?

Comment: You can get a [`Zone`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#zone) object using `IANAZone.create("Europe/London")` (see docs of [IANAZone.create](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#ianazonecreate)), but I fear that there is no 1 to 1 correspondence to moment's `offsets` and `untils`. Maybe you can use [`offset`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#zoneoffset) and other instance methods to get what you need.

Comment: @VincenzoC so maybe the only way would just be to determine the `untils` myself by looping through the range of time I'm interested in (usually only a few days), incrementing by 1 ms each time and passing to `offset()`, and storing an `until` at each change in `offset`.  In practice I can be more efficient, in the knowledge that my period of interest is only ~14 days at most... if `offset` is the same at the start and end then it won't (presumably) change in between... only need to determine the exact transition time (`until`) if the start/end `offset` is different.

Comment: @VincenzoC I posted an answer... maybe it's overly simplistic... any better ideas?

Comment: I do not have better ideas, your answer seems fine to me, especially if it meets your needs ;)

Comment: My main concern is the assumption that offsets only ever change on the hour.  But then again, in my use case it's not absolutely critical that I find the `untils` with millisecond accuracy... I'm not using this control a nuclear power station or to launch missiles.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @VincenzoC here is my simplistic attempt to get `offsets` and `untils` (as per `moment-timezone`) to cover the given time range.  This method assumes that offsets only ever change on the hour (so we can step through the time range by one hour increments).

```
import { IANAZone } from 'luxon';

const getZoneInfo = function (id, startTime, endTime) {
    startTime = Math.floor(startTime / 36e5) * 36e5; // move to previous whole hour
    endTime = Math.ceil(endTime / 36e5) * 36e5;      // move to next whole hour
    const increment = 36e5;                         // one whole hour
    const zone = IANAZone.create(id);
    const offsets = [];
    const untils = [];
    let offset, prevOffset;
    for (let time = startTime; time <= endTime; time += increment) {
        offset = zone.offset(time);
        if (prevOffset != undefined && offset != prevOffset || time == endTime) {
            offsets.push(-prevOffset);
            untils.push(time);
        }
        prevOffset = offset;
    }
    const zoneInfo = {
        id: id,
        offsets: offsets,
        untils: untils
    };
    console.log('zoneInfo', zoneInfo);
    return zoneInfo;
};

const startTime = 1646931245000;
const endTime = 1650473645000;
getZoneInfo('Europe/London', startTime, endTime);
getZoneInfo('Europe/Stockholm', startTime, endTime);
getZoneInfo('Asia/Tokyo', startTime, endTime);
getZoneInfo('America/New_York', startTime, endTime);
```

Output:

```
zoneInfo {
  id: 'Europe/London',
  offsets: [ -0, -60 ],
  untils: [ 1648342800000, 1650474000000 ]
}
zoneInfo {
  id: 'Europe/Stockholm',
  offsets: [ -60, -120 ],
  untils: [ 1648342800000, 1650474000000 ]
}
zoneInfo {
  id: 'Asia/Tokyo',
  offsets: [ -540 ],
  untils: [ 1650474000000 ]
}
zoneInfo {
  id: 'America/New_York',
  offsets: [ 300, 240 ],
  untils: [ 1647154800000, 1650474000000 ]
}
```

Of course, the final `until` does not represent an actual change in `offset`, but it serves the purpose to cover the entire range of interest (no need for anything beyond `endTime`).

**UPDATE**

Here is a variant of the above, which attempts to be a little more efficient (particularly for larger time ranges) by stepping through by full days and only going back to find the transition more accurately if there is a change in offset:

```
import { IANAZone } from 'luxon';

const getZoneInfo = function (id, startTime, endTime) {
    const zone = IANAZone.create(id);
    const offsets = [];
    const untils = [];
    startTime = Math.floor(startTime / 36e5) * 36e5;   // move to previous whole hour
    endTime = Math.ceil(endTime / 36e5) * 36e5;        // move to next whole hour
    const stepSmall = 36e5;                     // one whole hour
    const stepLarge = 24 * 36e5;                // one whole day
    let step = stepLarge;                       // start on the larger step for speed
    let offset, prevOffset, offsetChanged;
    let time = startTime;
    offset = prevOffset = zone.offset(time);
    do {
        time = Math.min(time + step, endTime);
        offset = zone.offset(time);
        offsetChanged = (offset != prevOffset);
        if (offsetChanged || time == endTime) {
            if (offsetChanged && step == stepLarge) {
                // go back a step and switch to using the smaller step to find the transition more accurately...
                time = time - stepLarge;
                step = stepSmall;
                continue;
            } else {
                offsets.push(-prevOffset);
                untils.push(time);
                // go back to the larger step...
                step = stepLarge;
            }
        }
        prevOffset = offset;

    } while (time < endTime);

    const zoneInfo = {
        id: id,
        offsets: offsets,
        untils: untils
    };
    console.log('zoneInfo', zoneInfo);

    return zoneInfo;
};


const startTime = 1608020493000;
const endTime = 1734250893000;
getZoneInfo('Europe/London', startTime, endTime);
getZoneInfo('Europe/Stockholm', startTime, endTime);
getZoneInfo('Asia/Tokyo', startTime, endTime);
getZoneInfo('America/New_York', startTime, endTime);
```

Output:

```
zoneInfo {
  id: 'Europe/London',
  offsets: [
    -0, -60, -0, -60,
    -0, -60, -0, -60,
    -0
  ],
  untils: [
    1616893200000,
    1635642000000,
    1648342800000,
    1667091600000,
    1679792400000,
    1698541200000,
    1711846800000,
    1729990800000,
    1734253200000
  ]
}
zoneInfo {
  id: 'Europe/Stockholm',
  offsets: [
     -60, -120,  -60,
    -120,  -60, -120,
     -60, -120,  -60
  ],
  untils: [
    1616893200000,
    1635642000000,
    1648342800000,
    1667091600000,
    1679792400000,
    1698541200000,
    1711846800000,
    1729990800000,
    1734253200000
  ]
}
zoneInfo {
  id: 'Asia/Tokyo',
  offsets: [ -540 ],
  untils: [ 1734253200000 ]
}
zoneInfo {
  id: 'America/New_York',
  offsets: [
    300, 240, 300,
    240, 300, 240,
    300, 240, 300
  ],
  untils: [
    1615705200000,
    1636264800000,
    1647154800000,
    1667714400000,
    1678604400000,
    1699164000000,
    1710054000000,
    1730613600000,
    1734253200000
  ]
}
```